# Emmet Package not showing in atom's Package section

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

i have watched a lot of Youtube tutorials and went through a lot of sites as well but I cant find Emmet Package in Atoms' Package section

Answer (score 0):

The Atom packages website and API have become extremely unreliable since GitHub announced its [sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/). Requests often fail with a status code of 500.

Your best option right now is to install Emmet manually, as described in the [README](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom):

```bash
cd ~/.atom/packages
git clone https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom
cd emmet-atom
npm install
```

The situation might improve once one of the two community forks, [Pulsar](https://github.com/pulsar-edit/pulsar) or [Atom Community](https://github.com/atom-community/atom), is ready to take over.